# How could a cell only have chromosomes from father or from mother?

Tags: chromosome, meiosis

How could arrangement one even be possible? How could a cell only have chromosomes from father or from mother?

[image]

[Image modified from "The laws of inheritance: Figure 5," by OpenStax College, Concepts of Biology, CC BY 4.0]

Comment: Hi! I suggest you read the guide on how to ask a good question: https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

For example, you might add an explanation on why you think the example is not reasonable, and we may be able to help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That graphic is just confusing you.

The cell doesn't keep track of all the chromosomes from Mother versus all the chromosomes from Father so it can sort them out later.  That I know of!  [I don't think imprinting counts because its effect varies between genes]  But the paternal and maternal chromosomes are still *separate* before meiosis - there hasn't been any meiotic crossing over during fertilization or mitosis!

So by *chance*, in this diagram, two chromosomes from one parent went one way, and two chromosomes from the other parent went the other.  For 2 chromsomes the odds are 50-50.  For 3 chromosomes the odds would be 1/8+1/8 = 1/4.  For 23 chromosomes the odds would be 1/4000000.

However, the figure isn't finished misleading you!  During prophase I, there is also [chromosomal crossover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromosomal_crossover) which exchanges segments between the two chromosomes.  So even in that very rare case when a child inherits one parent's form of all chromosomes ... it is still mixed in with stretches of the other parent's DNA.

I like OpenStax, but they are still in an early stage.  Their graphics are weak and many errors can be found.  But as long as you keep up this attitude of challenging your sources and asking questions, you can *thrive* using resources like this.